# Error In Laravel ClassLoader.php File

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

**Error:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$type' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')'","exception":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError","trace":[{"file":"/home/fiedel/Documents/fol/docs/develop/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php","line":322,

These are the things included:

```
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\RegistrySession;
use Auth;
use DB;
use App\Models\Registry;
use App\Models\Project;
use App\Models\Enterprise;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Group;
use League\Period\Period;
use Marcelgwerder\ApiHandler\Facades\ApiHandler;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use PHPExcel;
use PHPExcel_IOFactory;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;
use App\Models\DailyLog\CaptionDailyUser;
use App\Models\DailyLog\CaptionDailyUserProject;
use App\Models\DailyLog\UserActivityDaily;
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Post your $type variable here... Not just the 'use '